# Hibernate 5.4.29 -> native Query needs Scalar?

Tags: java, hibernate

we are currently upgrading to Hibernate 5.4.29.

We have some custom Usertypes that map for example bigint to a custom usertype (extends Usertype).

```
 metadata.applyBasicType(new MyUserType(), new String[] { MyUserType.class.getName()});
```

If I create a native query with the new version e.g.

```
hibernate.createNativeQuery(select * from tablexy);
```

and one of the columns contains bigint values it tries to map the type to the custom Usertype MyUserType.

This seems to be happening in the class JdbcResultMetadata

```
//Get the contributed Hibernate Type first
    Set<String> hibernateTypeNames = factory.getMetamodel()
            .getTypeConfiguration()
            .getJdbcToHibernateTypeContributionMap()
            .get( columnType );

    //If the user has not supplied any JDBC Type to Hibernate Type mapping, use the Dialect-based mapping
    if ( hibernateTypeNames != null && !hibernateTypeNames.isEmpty() ) {
        if ( hibernateTypeNames.size() > 1 ) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    String.format(
                            "There are multiple Hibernate types: [%s] registered for the [%d] JDBC type code",
                            String.join( ", ", hibernateTypeNames ),
                            columnType
                    ) );
        }
        else {
            hibernateTypeName = hibernateTypeNames.iterator().next();
        }
    }
    else {
        hibernateTypeName = factory.getDialect().getHibernateTypeName(
                columnType,
                length,
                precision,
                scale
        );
    }

    return factory.getTypeResolver().heuristicType(
            hibernateTypeName
    );
```

If we use the native query without adding a scalar we get:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: There are multiple Hibernate types: [MyUserType1, MyUserType2] registered for the [-5] JDBC type code
```

This can be prevented if I add addScalar() for every column. Which is quite cumbersome. The old hibernate version did not map to the usertypes unless we explicitly added e.g. a ResultTransformer.

Do we have to add addScalar for every column if we don't want mapping to usertypes or is there some other way to prevent this. (Basically I want a native query where the results are not mapped to the usertypes without adding addScalar for every column)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom `org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataContributor` or `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` (register it through the service loader mechanism) and remove type mappings that you don't want by altering the map `metadataCollector.getBootstrapContext().getTypeConfiguration().getJdbcToHibernateTypeContributionMap()` or `sessionFactory.getMetamodel().getTypeConfiguration().getJdbcToHibernateTypeContributionMap()`

I actually think this might be a bug, but I'm not sure at all.